# Group by composite key and then select one distinct column by MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a MySQL table t_table as below, which has millions of records.

```
id        c_key1               c_key2      ...
 1          123                 abc
 2          123                 bcd
 3          234                 acd
 4          234                 ads
```

Composite key: composite_key(c_key1, c_key2).

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT c_key1 
FROM
  t_table 
GROUP BY 
  c_key1, c_key2
HAVING 
  COUNT(1) >= 2;
```

But the explain plan has "Using temporary; Using filesort", which slower the speed. Is there any way to optimize?

Comment: What are you trying to find here?  Before worrying about optimization you should make sure you have the right query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah. The SQL above is just my first thought, but it has performance issue. So I am trying to find out a better query. Finally I got one.

Comment: You didn't answer my question :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here is it: From business view, (c_key1, c_key2) should be unique. But at the very beginning (c_key1, c_key2) is just a composite key, not unique. Also, there is problem with application, inserting duplicated records into t_table. So now I want to find out the duplicated records and extract distinct c_key1, then do something based on that. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_key1
    FROM t_table t1 
INNER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT 
    MIN(t3.id) as id 
  FROM 
    t_table t3 
  GROUP BY t3.c_key1, t3.c_key2
  HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
  ) t2
  ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

I think I got a better one(maybe not the best). The explain plan shows t1 is using primary key and t3 the composite index. As for the derived table, it's using temporary, no filesort at least. The elapsed time of above SQL is several times shorter than the one in question.

Let me try to do more optimization:)